# Matlab: Applying formula to new field in a structure array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, structure

Thank you in advance...

Essentially I would like to add a new field(Max_Heart_Rate) to a structure array that that computes maximum heart rate for each person. I want to reference another field (Age) when computing max heart rate. I have this but it generates an error which I can not figure out.

```
 Study_Data.Max_Heart_Rate = 200 - [Study_Data.Age]
```

I have also tried

```
C = num2cell(1:100)
[Study_Data(:).Max_Heart_Rate] = deal(C{:})
Study_Data.Max_Heart_Rate = 200 - [Study_Data.Age]
```

Additionally, I have tried...

Study_Data.Max_Heart_Rate = (200 - (Study_Data.Age(:))

But Matlab expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing but there were 100 outputs.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Can you post a sample structure? Since you said that you want to do it for each person, I am assuming your problem is that Study_Data.Age is not a single value